# the difference of orbitControls in potree and three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm using Potree (https://github.com/potree/potree) for the visualization of a massive point cloud.But the orbitControls doesn't meet my requirements. When i use mouseright to panup, the height of camera will be changed. When i use orbitControls in some three.js demos, this won't happen. So what the difference of orbitControls in three.js and Potree?

Comment: Guessing... try `controls.screenSpacePanning = false;`, but you should show your code when you ask a question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Potree uses its own version of OrbitControls (heavily modified and lacking many properties from original OrbitControls). Use can find it in Potree source code and see for yourself what's missing